# Share posts programmatically in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I want to share to `Facebook` each new post in my `wordpress` site. Which hook is necessary for this task?

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work =(

```
function on_all_status_transitions $new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if ($new_status == 'publish') {
        $url = 'http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' . get_permalink($post->ID);
        wp_redirect($url);
        // header('Location: '. $url); -> it doesn't work too =(
    }
}
add_action('transition_post_status', 'on_all_status_transitions', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `publish_post` hook, this triggered whenever a post is published

```
function on_all_status_transitions( $ID, $post) {     
        $url = 'http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' . get_permalink($ID);
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;           
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'on_all_status_transitions', 10, 3 );
```

[check this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post)

Comment: Thank you, but in doesn't solve my task. And it works the same logic, like in my code.

Comment: I want to share my posts without visiting facebook.com. I don't want to click Share after redirect. Is it possible?

Comment: yes check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.1

Comment: I can't use this abilities in my test local site. Am I right ?

Comment: yes you can, by creating an app in Facebook, had you created it?

Comment: Yes, I did. I try use this link https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=815369501849154&redirect_uri=http://wordpress . After that I have an error message "URL does not match the settings of the application: One or more of the URL- address is blocked application settings. The address must match the address of the web site or location of the canvas , or the domain must be a subdomain of a domain application."

Comment: ok if you are testing in local make sure the site url must be http://localhost/yoursite

Comment: Is it necessary? If yes, why ?

Comment: yes it is necessary if you are testing in a local server.